# Silence git (no errors, no output, don't say a word)

Tags: git, bash, silent

I'm using git to manage some custom packages. If the package is not in the first repo, I want to run a second command that tries another source. I don't need to tell the user that this is happening. The user doesn't need to know git exists.

```
if ! git clone git@gitlab.com:username/repo directory -q
        then
            #do something else
        fi
```

git still prints a fatal error in the console even with `-q`.

So, how do I silence the little git?

Comment: Perhaps `>/dev/null 2>&1`

Comment: @bishop yep, that'll do it. cheers. add it as an answer for others if you don't mind.

Comment: @axiac `Could not read from remote repository`, which is expected.

Comment: Nevermind, I thought the error was displayed by the shell (a syntax error or something like this). I was not aware of this way to check the return code of a command (I always ran the command then checked `$?` in the `if` statement).

Comment: Glad it worked. Give @Paul the points!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Two ways:

`git clone git@gitlab.com:username/repo directory > /dev/null 2>&1` - older bash

and:

`git clone git@gitlab.com:username/repo directory &> /dev/null` - newer bash (Above version 4 according to the link below)

For more details read about [I/O Redirection in Bash](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/io-redirection.html).
Essentially what you're doing here is redirect both `stdout` and `stderr` to `/dev/null`, which is "nowhere".

Comment: which is the most compatible?

Comment: The "older bash" version is the portable version that works in all shells. The "newer bash" version relies on a non-conforming extension that may not even be available at all: I don't know if bash disables it in POSIX mode, but even if it doesn't, it's supposed to, so a future version might.

Comment: Yep, the **older** version is more portable/compatible!

Answer (score 0):

git clone git@gitlab.com:username/repo directory > /dev/null 2>&1 - older bash

Above will be more compatible,